# async/await in MVVM without Void methods

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, async-await

I want to use async/await on my windows phone 8 MVVM project and I'm struggling to find a good way to implement my ICommands using this api.
I've been reading a few articles about the subject and I bumped into this one from MSDN below, which states that I have to avoid async voids since it gets difficult to catch unhandled exceptions:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx 
In another question I asked about the subject, someone also said that I shouldn't use async voids. Unless with events.

But the problem is that all examples I can find on the internet use async voids.
This two articles I found are examples:
http://richnewman.wordpress.com/2012/12/03/tutorial-asynchronous-programming-async-and-await-for-beginners/ and
http://blog.mycupof.net/2012/08/23/mvvm-asyncdelegatecommand-what-asyncawait-can-do-for-uidevelopment/

The last one is an implementation of ICommand using async/await, but it also uses async voids.
I'm trying to come up with a solution for this, so I wrote this implementation of ICommand based on the RelayCommand:

```cs
public delegate Task AsyncAction();

public class RelayCommandAsync : ICommand
{
    private AsyncAction _handler;
    public RelayCommandAsync(AsyncAction handler)
    {
        _handler = handler;
    }

    private bool _isEnabled;
    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get { return _isEnabled; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _isEnabled)
            {
                _isEnabled = value;
                if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
                {
                    CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return IsEnabled;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        ExecuteAsync();
    }

    private Task ExecuteAsync()
    {
        return _handler();
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to use it like this:
in the constructor:

```cs
saveCommand = new RelayCommandAsync(SaveSourceAsync);
```

then:

```cs
private async Task SaveSourceAsync()
{
    await Task.Run(() => { Save(); });
}

private void Save()
{
    // Slow operation
}
```

The problem is that I'm not feeling comfortable with this and any other implementation as I don't know which is the best and optimal.

Can anyone give some light on how I should use it, preferably with MVVM?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the referenced article, I did point out that `ICommand.Execute` is practically an event handler, so it would be considered an exception from the "avoid `async void`" guideline:

> To summarize this first guideline, you should prefer async Task to async void... The exception to this guideline is asynchronous event handlers, which must return void. This exception includes methods that are logically event handlers even if they’re not literally event handlers (for example, ICommand.Execute implementations).

Regarding your `ICommand` implementation, it actually introduces a flaw by *not* using `async void`: the `ICommand.Execute` implementation will discard the `Task` without observing its exceptions. So that implementation will ignore any exceptions raised by the `async` delegate.

In contrast, the blog post you linked to has an `async void ICommand.Execute` which `await`s the `Task`, allowing the exception to propagate to the UI synchronization context. Which - in this case - is the desired behavior because it's the same behavior you get when a synchronous `ICommand.Execute` raises an exception.

If you have the inclination, I'd like you to try out an `ICommand` or two that I've written for possible future inclusion in my [AsyncEx library](https://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com). The [first one](https://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Source/Nito.AsyncEx.Mvvm%20%28NET45,%20Win8,%20SL4,%20WP75%29/SimpleAsyncCommand.cs) is a simple command very similar to the one in the blog you posted. The [second one](https://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Source/Nito.AsyncEx.Mvvm%20%28NET45,%20Win8,%20SL4,%20WP75%29/AsyncCommand.cs) is a much more complete "asynchronous command" implementation including cancellation, progress reporting, and automatic management of `CanExecute`. I'd appreciate any feedback.

Comment: I'm taking a look in your lib and implementations.
So tell me something, with the ICommand implementation for the blog post I put here, if an exception occurs will if raise the unhandled exception event in Windows Phone App.xaml?
I'm gonna test it later.

Comment: I was taking a look into the `SimpleAsyncCommand`, looks like it works form my purposes, I just want to know: My nethod that `ExecuteAsync` is gonna call is going to be running in the UIs contexts and I'd have to use `await Task.Run` within this method, right? Will I lose any exceptions working like this? If not I think I'm gonna use your lib!

Comment: Exceptions from `ICommand`s will be raised on the WP UI, so they will be sent to `Application.UnhandledException`. `ExecuteAsync` will be executed on the UI thread (so your `async` delegate will start running on the UI thread). You can use `await Task.Run` if you have blocking work to do for that command; if you have asynchronous work to do, you wouldn't need `Task.Run` and can just use `await`. And it's not actually part of my lib yet; you'll just have to copy the source for now.

Comment: Oh, if I have an operation like saving data to the database for example, I won't need `Task.Run`?
Like, if I put the code for saving data within a method that returns `Task` and await it, won't it block the UI? Task.Run would be only for something REALLY intensive like accessing a webservice? is thats what you mean? If it is, it's beautiful! hahahaha =)

Comment: Databases are iffy right now. They *should* be naturally asynchronous, but many DB APIs don't support that (yet). So if you have some kind of `SaveChangesAsync` or whatever in your DB API, then you can just `await` it directly, no need for `Task.Run`. Webservices have much better asynchronous support, e.g., `HttpClient` has `GetAsync` etc. which you can `await` directly. `Task.Run` is actually meant for CPU-intensive (not I/O-bound) code, but it *can* be used to make synchronous APIs look asynchronous if you need to.

Comment: Cool. I'm using windows phone's native database and I don't know if it supports async operations. And I don't know if it would have any problems using db contexts like: `using (var db = new Context()) { //... async db.SaveChanges(); }`. do you know if it works?

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't used it, so I don't know.